# Emergency Mode!! on LG P350

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lg

I am using LG P350 from long time as my backup mobile. Some how Emergency Mode!! has triggered. Please some one help me out solving this problem

Answer (score -2):

Don't worry, you should be able to get out of it. It can commonly happen among Android users when a certain key combination is pressed on accident. You can refer to [this link](http://www.smartmobilephonesolutions.com/content/phone-stuck-in-emergency-mode) for causes and fixes.

Comment: I tried that but there is no use. Still it is showing the same.

Comment: A link-only answer becomes irrelevant the moment link dies. Consider incorporating the relevant info (from the link) into the answer to make the latter self-sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but the original asker has already said that the answer I provided doesn't help his case.